# Amazon Web Services load balancer forwarding to listener does not work if forwarding from the same instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tcp, load-balancing

I have the following situation set up in Amazon Web Services: [AWS setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbSyO.jpg).

Requests from the internet enter the load balancer through port 443, and a listener makes sure this traffic gets forwarded to the instance on port 8080 (to application A).
Another listener on the load balancer forwards traffic from port 8041 to port 8050 on the instance (to application B).
It's possible for application A to perform a REST call to the load balancer on port 8041, which would end up at application B.

Inbound rules set up **sg-1** security group on diagram:

- 443/tcp from 0.0.0.0/0 (connection from internet)
- 8041/tcp from sg-2 (connection from application A)

Inbound rules set up **sg-2** security group on diagram:

- 22/tcp from 0.0.0.0/0 (SSH)
- 8050/tcp from sg-1 (connection to application B)
- 8080/tcp from sg-1 (connection to application A)

Unfortunately, application A fails to reach application B through the load balancer on port 8041.
However, once I allow inbound connections on the ports above from all sources (instead of specific security groups), suddenly application can make the REST call to application B on port 8041.

I suspect it might have something to do with the instance in sg-1 ending up in sg-1 again through the load balancer.
Application B is reported "healthy" by the load balancer, so something seems to be wrong with connecting to the load balancer on port 8041, or the forwarding to port 8050 of the instance.

I've tried to call application B directly by its internal DNS name, instead of calling application B through the load balancer in application A. This works.

I'm out of ideas. My configuration seems to be fine, but still calls don't get through. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When you specify a security group as the source for a rule, this
>   allows instances associated with the source security group to access
>   instances in the security group.  (...) Incoming traffic is allowed
>   based on the private IP addresses of the instances that are associated
>   with the source security group (and not the public IP or Elastic IP
>   addresses).

When your application A is connecting to (external) Load Balancer, it will connect to LB public IP, with app A public IP as source address, therefore sg-1 ID can't be used in sg-2 rules. I see 2 options here:

1. Create another, [Internal Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-internal-load-balancers.html), and use it to access from app A to app B (LB name will resolve to private IPs and security group ID can be used in rules)
2. Instead of using appA security group ID in sg-2 rules, use appA public IP address (this may not be optimal if you expect any changes in appA public IP address)